# Use of Apache Kafka stream builder

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have been trying Apache Kafka open source producer and consumer data streaming. I have a question, what is the difference in using 1.) `KafkaProducer, producer.send` and 
2.) `Streamsbuilder, KafkaStreams` code? Are they not both for kafka streaming data?
If i just use `KafkaProducer, producer.send`, can't I achieve streaming of data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kafka Streams for more complex data processing as it provides a high and low level processor API's.Here in low level processor api you get control over records and create a flow(topology) in which you can manipulate the records in different ways and send it to one or more output topics.
In high level you have k-tables that has functionality such as join.
These support windowing and other functions that give more control over the data being picked up.
State  stores are also available in Kafka Streams that help in statefull transformations.Plus its easy to scale horizontally and vertically in Kafka streams

Comment: Excellent! I have read somewhere an another point too, Kafka streams API is the one that supports queued streaming data (for ex: continuous feeds etc.), standard API doesn't support such data streaming.

Comment: Kiran, Could you also share if you have links and documents for the explanation? I can read all feature difference completely. Thanks for you answer.